# Android Google Plus Login

Tags: android, google-plus

I use google plus login example and its worked fine !

but after compile application and install it ! when I want to login with google plus it show 
toast with this message : 'an internal error occurred'

please help me !

thanks

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/22/android-login-using-google/#more-157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason I had this error was that I needed to implement the Public API access key in the Google console. The most important piece of info here is the SHA1 number this tutorial worked for me on windows http://livingcode.co/index.php/2014/04/10/android-studio-how-to-get-debug-signing-certificate-on-windows/ and the app identifier eg com.example.app. I still had the error after that until I figured out I needed to implement the OAuth key too, oh and make sure that you add your email address to the consent screen.